# HOG Detection methods

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

i am new to Computer vision and Machine learning, i searched a lot but did not find quite answer for my questions.

First: I want to know what is the difference between all of these detection methods.

1)`HOG.detect()`

2)`HOG.detectMultiScale()`

3)`HOG.setSvmDetector()`

Second: I read that `HOG.setSvmDetector()` used only for detecting one object since SVM is a binary classfication, i was wondering can we train  multi class SVM (One vs All) and for each single class of SVM we apply a new instance of `HOG.setSvmDetector()` ?

for an examlpe if i constructed 2 SVM's which means now i have Multi class SVM of 2 classes can i do smth like this:

> HOGDescriptor hog1 = newHOGDescriptor()
>
> HOGDescriptor hog2 = new HOGDescriptor()
>
> hog1.setSvmDetector( CLASS ONE )
>
> hog2.setSvmDetector( CLASS TWO )

Answer (score 1):

`HOG.detect`
It detects objects in a single image.

`HOG.detectMultiScale`
It detects objects in image with original size then downsample the image using a certain factor e.g. using 1.2 as factor. It then detects objects in downsampled image and further downsample the image. This process is repeated until image size is less than the detection window size. It then combines all the detections found over all the images.

`HOG.setSvmDetector()`
It is used to set the trained classifier. OpenCV provides you the pretrained classifier over different datasets like getDefaultPeopleDetector() (trained using INRIA pedestrian dataset) and getDaimlerPeopleDetector() (trained using Daimler pedestrian dataset).

You can also trained your own classifier either binary or multiclass and use it in setSvmDetector()..